# My php wont do anything? Using Contacts API of google

Tags: php, api, google-app-engine, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to make an website in which you can import contacts from gmail and add them as friends within the website. For now I'm only trying to show the contacts of the one whom clicks on the `<a>`. I've followed an tutorial and everything should work, but it doesn't. It does show the `<H2>` at the top, but not the `<a>` which is actually important. My google secret and client id are correct, but I'd rather not just show them. The path to the google php API is correct as well, but I think something is going wrong there since it doesn't recognize any php.

app.yaml:

```
application: csimporttest
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: .*
  script: response-callback.php
```

Response-callback.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<h2>ttest</h2>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>

<?php
session_start();

//include google api library
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';// or wherever autoload.php is located

$google_client_id = 'Google Client Id';
$google_client_secret = 'Google Secret';
$google_redirect_uri = 'https://csimporttest.appspot.com';

//setup new google client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('csimporttest');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

$client -> setScopes('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');

$googleImportUrl = $client -> createAuthUrl();

function curl($url, $post = "") {
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
 if ($post != "") {
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 }
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
 //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
 //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['google_code'])) {
 $auth_code = $_SESSION['google_code'];
 $max_results = 200;
    $fields=array(
        'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
        'client_id'=>  urlencode($google_client_id),
        'client_secret'=>  urlencode($google_client_secret),
        'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($google_redirect_uri),
        'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
    );
    $post = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $post = rtrim($post,'&');
    $result = curl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',$post);
    $response =  json_decode($result);
    $accesstoken = $response->access_token;
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
    $xmlresponse =  curl($url);
    $contacts = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);

 $return = array();
 if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
 foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
           //retrieve Name and email address  
 $return[] = array (
 'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
 'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
 );
 } 
 }

echo ';print_r($google_contacts);echo ';

 unset($_SESSION['google_code']);

}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $googleImportUrl; ?>"> Import google contacts </a>

<?php

 if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
 foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
            //retrieve Name and email address  
 $return[] = array (
 'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
 'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
 );

            //retrieve user photo
 if (isset($contact['link'][0]['href'])) {

 $url =   $contact['link'][0]['href'];

 $url = $url . '&access_token=' . urlencode($accesstoken);

 $curl = curl_init($url);

         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

         $image = curl_exec($curl);
         curl_close($curl);

 }

                        $return['image'] = $image;

                        echo '';

 } 
 }

?>

</html></body>
```

Comment: You may want to run the resulting HTML through a validator. You have errors. Also, but this could be just me, the value of the `$userAgent` variable makes me want to cry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an var_dump() to see if the array google_contacts is actually filled.  Put this in the main.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($google_contacts);
?>
```

If you get an output in the var_dump you can use an html table and an easy foreach, look below:

```
<table border='1' class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Naam </th>
    <th>Email </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($google_contacts as $contacts){
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['name']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['email'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're correct - **never** show your client ID and secret.

There are a number of things that are unclear about what you're posting, including how, exactly, you're getting the google_code session variable set, but I would suggest debugging along the following lines:

- Look at the full value from `$result`. It may be returning an error code which might indicate why it isn't loading the contacts.
- Double-check the token URL endpoint. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer says it should be `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`, but I've seen the URL listed differently in the past, so I never know which one is actually valid.
- Make sure you have authorized the Contact API in the Google Developers Console and make sure, as you go through the authorization window, that it asks for permission to access your contacts.

Comment: trying to debug right now with sublime text and google app engine(never done this so its kind of a hassle... ) I have changed the URL endpoint and it didnt help. I'm thinking right now that the error lies somewhere else...